# By using HTML5 canvas, how to create infinite loop with time interval

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I want to keep updating my image position with HTML5 canvas. I tried the following javascript code to do the work

```
window.onload = function start() {
  update();
}

function update() {
  document.getElementById('scoreband').innerHTML = score;
  var style = document.getElementById('bug').style;
  timmer = window.setInterval(function () {
    style.left = ((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + "%";
    style.top = ((Math.random() * 100) + 19) + "%";
  }, num);
}
```

But this is not working when it comes to HTML5 canvas. Is there similar way to do the same job in HTML5 canvas?

Comment: Where are `score` and `num` defined?

Comment: @guest271314 var score = 0; var num = 1;

Comment: Note: if `#bug` is a `<canvas>`, this not how you should be moving your image. Use its `drawImage()` method instead. Here, you'll force a repaint of the whole page at each frame, for nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change any visual DOM content you should use requestAmimationFrame

Eg

```
function update(time){
   // time is in ms and has a 1/1000000 second accuracy 
   // code that changes some content, like the canvas


   requestAnimationFrame(update);  // requests the next frame in 1/60th second
}
```

And to start it

```
requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

As requested

```
indow.onload = function start() {
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}

function update() {
  document.getElementById('scoreband').innerHTML = score;
  var style = document.getElementById('bug').style;
  style.left = ((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + "%";
  style.top = ((Math.random() * 100) + 19) + "%";
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
}
```

Comment: How to change the time interval

Comment: You can not change the interval but you do get the time as part of the callback and you can use that to set any time related info. Will update answer

Comment: Ok, can u give me a complete example for my circumstance?

Answer (score 1):

Though it’s not as good as requestAnimationFrame, setInterval’s frame rate can be dynamic.

```
//supposing num is defined lol
var timer = setInterval(update, num);
function update() {
  document.getElementById('scoreband').innerHTML = score;
  var style = document.getElementById('bug').style;
    style.left = ((Math.random() * 100) + 1) + "%";
    style.top = ((Math.random() * 100) + 19) + "%";
}
```